# Extraer parte de un texto que se encuentra en el medio de una cadena

Tags: c#, string

Necesito extraer un texto que se encuentra en medio de una cadena mediante, pero no sé cómo.

El texto es el siguiente:

```
string cadena =jy193UAhUHJsAKHV4rD904PBAWCC0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icali.es%2FPORTAL_ICALI%2FprintPortal.do%3FurlPagina%3DS005013001%2Fes_ES.html&usg=AFQjCNH-c6dVemIxU_GaSYgoGPNXWVztIA
```

El texto que tengo que extraer es una URL que se encuentra limitada por  `&url=`  y `&usg=`. Esta URL creo que está codificada en hexadecimal, si no me engaño, y si sabéis cómo convertir esa URL a texto normal, ya sería la caña.

Ejemplo:

> ```
> &url=(Aquí va la url)&usg=
> ```

Pensé en solucionarlo con expresiones regulares. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Por qué con expresiones regulares? ¿No te sería más sencillo extraer directamente el texto entre `&url=` y `&usg=` buscando la posición de esas cadenas?

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de reetiquetar la pregunta para no limitarlo a regex. Si no estás de acuerdo, no dudes en revertirlo o en comentarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Otra solución un poco rebuscada podría ser hacer un substring a partir de los índices de esos dos elementos. Algo así:

```
string cadena = "jy193UAhUHJsAKHV4rD904PBAWCC0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icali.es%2FPORTAL_ICALI%2FprintPortal.do%3FurlPagina%3DS005013001%2Fes_ES.html&usg=AFQjCNH-c6dVemIxU_GaSYgoGPNXWVztIA";
// Obtenemos la posición del &url= + 5 para obtener la posición del =
int indice1 = cadena.IndexOf("&url=") + "&url=".Length; 
// Obtenemos la posición del &usrg=
int indice2 = cadena.IndexOf("&usg=");
// Restamos los índices para saber cuantos caracteres tenemos que coger
int caracteres = indice2 - indice1;
// Finalmente hacemos un substring del primer índice, cogiendo el número de caracteres necesarios. 
string cadena2 = cadena.Substring(indice1, caracteres);
```

Comment: En vez de usar `+ 5`, quizás convenga generalizar tu respuesta con `"&url=".Length` (o usando variables para los límites)

Comment: @Mariano Tienes razón, poniéndolo así es más claro. Lo he cambiado

Comment: No creo que sea rebuscada, todo lo contrario, mucho más sencilla que las alternativas propuestas, y es la forma en la que le recomendaría a alguien que está iniciando con el lenguaje... entender los principios básicos. Buena respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, por lo que veo todas las respuestas van encaminadas a usar `System.Web`, en caso de que no puedas o no quieras utilizarlo te pongo otra posible solución.

```
string cadena = "jy193UAhUHJsAKHV4rD904PBAWCC0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icali.es%2FPORTAL_ICALI%2FprintPortal.do%3FurlPagina%3DS005013001%2Fes_ES.html&usg=AFQjCNH-c6dVemIxU_GaSYgoGPNXWVztIA";
        if (cadena.Contains("&url=") && cadena.Contains("&usg="))
        {
            var subCadena = cadena.Split(new string[]{"&url=", "&usg="},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.StartsWith("http")).FirstOrDefault() ;
            string url =Uri.UnescapeDataString(subCadena);

        }
```

Un saludo, y espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @Mariano, no parece necesario usar un regex para lo que intentas conseguir. Yo lo que haría sería separar la cadena usando `Split` con las dos cadenas separadoras como parámetros, y despues comprobar cual de las cadenas comienza por `http`. Posteriormente, para decodificar la url puedes utilizar el método [`UrlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/adwtk1fy(v=vs.110).aspx) de `System.Web`:

```
string cadena = "jy193UAhUHJsAKHV4rD904PBAWCC0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icali.es%2FPORTAL_ICALI%2FprintPortal.do%3FurlPagina%3DS005013001%2Fes_ES.html&usg=AFQjCNH-c6dVemIxU_GaSYgoGPNXWVztIA";
var url = System.Web.HttpUtility
           .UrlDecode(cadena.Split(new string[] { "&url=", "&usg" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Where(x=>x.StartsWith("http")).FirstOrDefault());

//en url obtenemos http://www.icali.es/PORTAL_ICALI/printPortal.do?urlPagina=S005013001/es_ES.html
```

---

En realidad,en lugar de tener que importar el ensamblado `System.Web`, es mejor usar `Uri.UnescapeDataString` como bien dice @Gerardo

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, habría que saber el tipo de desarrollo que usa @Alonso. Si no es de tipo Web, no creo que pueda usar el ensamblado `System.Web`. Saludos

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede usar el ensamblado `System.Web` en una aplicacion de otro tipo, por ejemplo de consola @SergioParraGuerra

Comment: Hola, me expliqué mal la verdad. Importar ese "mega" ensamblado para emplear un método Helper no me parece muy eficiente la verdad. Voy a proponer otra respuesta. Gracias y saludos

Comment: Eso es diferente @SergioParraGuerra. Como dice alguien en otra respuesta, `Uri.UnescapeDataString` probablemente sea mejor en este caso

Answer (score 1):

si usas el ensamblado `System.Web` en tu desarrollo puedes emplear el método [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) para crear una colección de `NameValueCollection` y poder manejar los parámetros de la cadena. En el enlace hay este ejemplo.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    String currurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
    String querystring = null ;

    // Check to make sure some query string variables
    // exist and if not add some and redirect.
    int iqs = currurl.IndexOf('?');
    if (iqs == -1)
    {
      String redirecturl = currurl + "?var1=1&var2=2+2%2f3&var1=3";
      Response.Redirect(redirecturl, true); 
    }
    // If query string variables exist, put them in
    // a string.
    else if (iqs >= 0)
    {
      querystring = (iqs < currurl.Length - 1) ? currurl.Substring(iqs + 1) : String.Empty;
    }

    // Parse the query string variables into a NameValueCollection.
    NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);

    // Iterate through the collection.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<br />");
    foreach (String s in qscoll.AllKeys)
    {
      sb.Append(s + " - " + qscoll[s] + "<br />");
    }

    // Write the result to a label.
    ParseOutput.Text = sb.ToString();

  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>HttpUtility ParseQueryString Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      Query string variables are:
      <asp:Label  id="ParseOutput"
                  runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el ejemplo en tu respuesta? La idea de las respuestas del  sitio es que estén completas, sin la necesidad de ir a otro recurso. Los enlaces son útiles para agregar más información, pero no para aportar lo central de tu respuesta.

Comment: editada la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

también puedes "parsear", sin emplear el ensamblado `System.Web`, la cadena generando un NameValueCollection y acceder a sus elementos. (basado en el blog de Rick Strahl [A .NET QueryString and Form Data Parser](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Sep/08/A-NET-QueryString-and-Form-Data-Parser)

### Crear una clase parseadora

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

/// <summary>
/// A query string or UrlEncoded form parser and editor 
/// class that allows reading and writing of urlencoded
/// key value pairs used for query string and HTTP 
/// form data.
/// 
/// Useful for parsing and editing querystrings inside
/// of non-Web code that doesn't have easy access to
/// the HttpUtility class.                
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Supports multiple values per key
/// </remarks>
public class UrlEncodingParser : NameValueCollection
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds the original Url that was assigned if any
    /// Url must contain // to be considered a url
    /// </summary>
    private string Url { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Always pass in a UrlEncoded data or a URL to parse from
    /// unless you are creating a new one from scratch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryStringOrUrl">
    /// Pass a query string or raw Form data, or a full URL.
    /// If a URL is parsed the part prior to the ? is stripped
    /// but saved. Then when you write the original URL is 
    /// re-written with the new query string.
    /// </param>
    public UrlEncodingParser(string queryStringOrUrl = null)
    {
        Url = string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryStringOrUrl))
        {
            Parse(queryStringOrUrl);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Assigns multiple values to the same key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="values"></param>
    public void SetValues(string key, IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        foreach (var val in values)
            Add(key, val);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the query string into the internal dictionary
    /// and optionally also returns this dictionary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query">
    /// Query string key value pairs or a full URL. If URL is
    /// passed the URL is re-written in Write operation
    /// </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public NameValueCollection Parse(string query)
    {
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(query, UriKind.Absolute))
            Url = query;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            Clear();
        else
        {
            int index = query.IndexOf('?');
            if (index > -1)
            {
                if (query.Length >= index + 1)
                    query = query.Substring(index + 1);
            }

            var pairs = query.Split('&');
            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                int index2 = pair.IndexOf('=');
                if (index2 > 0)
                {
                    Add(pair.Substring(0, index2), pair.Substring(index2 + 1));
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes out the urlencoded data/query string or full URL based 
    /// on the internally set values.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>urlencoded data or url</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        foreach (string key in Keys)
        {
            string[] values = GetValues(key);
            foreach (var val in values)
            {
                query += key + "=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(val) + "&";
            }
        }
        query = query.Trim('&');

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
        {
            if (Url.Contains("?"))
                query = Url.Substring(0, Url.IndexOf('?') + 1) + query;
            else
                query = Url + "?" + query;
        }

        return query;
    }
}
```

### Crear la aplicación de consola

```
namespace TestExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var query = "jy193UAhUHJsAKHV4rD904PBAWCC0wAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.icali.es%2FPORTAL_ICALI%2FprintPortal.do%3FurlPagina%3DS005013001%2Fes_ES.html&usg=AFQjCNH-c6dVemIxU_GaSYgoGPNXWVztIA";

            var urlQuery = new UrlEncodingParser(query);

            foreach (string key in urlQuery.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{key} {Uri.UnescapeDataString(urlQuery[key])}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

### Salida del programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]